# how to show inner on mouse hover of outer div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-3.5

i just want to show inner div on mouse hover of outer div.
here is my jquery for show div on mouse hover:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('.thumb').hover(function(){
    $('.option').show();
});
});
</script>
```

and here is my design code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt_file_list" runat="server" 
onitemcommand="rpt_file_list_ItemCommand" 
onitemdatabound="rpt_file_list_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
<div class="thumb" align="center">
<table>
<tr>
<td align="center"><asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server" BorderWidth="0px" 
ImageUrl="../images/Nofile_Icon1.gif" />
<br/>
<asp:Label ID="lbl_file_length" runat="server" CssClass="normaltext" 
Text='<%#"("+ Eval("File_Size")+ " KB )"%>'></asp:Label>
<br/>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbut_download" runat="server" 
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("File_name")+""+Eval("File_ext")%>' CommandName="Download" 
Text='<%#Eval("File_Title").ToString().Length > 15 ? Eval("File_Title").ToString().Substring(0, 15) + "..." : Eval("File_Title")%>' 
ToolTip='<%#Bind("File_Title")%>'></asp:LinkButton></td>
<td valign="top"><div class="option" align="right" style="display:none">
<table>
<tr><td><asp:ImageButton ID="imbtn_download" runat="server" CommandName="Download" ImageUrl="../images/download.gif" ToolTip="Download"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton5" runat="server" CommandName="Preview" ImageUrl="../images/view.gif" ToolTip="Preview"/></td></tr>
</table>
</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblErrorMsg" runat="server" Text="No files found." Visible="false" ForeColor="Red">
</asp:Label>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

how ever it's not work properly 
please help me...

Comment: show Inner ? you mean children of outer div

Comment: there is two div outer with thumb class and inner with option class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the descendant element of the hovered `thumb`, also you need to use toggle() so that it will get hidden when mouse leaves

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.thumb').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.option').toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('.thumb').mouseover(function () {
                $('.option').show();
            });
            $('.thumb').mouseout(function () {
                $('.option').hide();
            });
        });
```

Comment: this works fine. but i have multiple divs with class thumb and option and when on one div mouse hover it display all inner div of all outer div. how ever i just only want to show single inner div which hover from user

Comment: @shal you can give an additional class name for the required div. then the selecter will be like $('.thumb.newclassname').mouseover

Answer (score 1):

You just need to find the options

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('.thumb').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.option').toggle(); //this will take care of show hide
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".thumb").hover(function(){
     $(".option").toggle();    

   });

});
```

fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/6a6Fx/1/

Answer (score 0):

**[hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)** take two handler which are fired when your mouse enter the div and when your mouse leave the div. Also, you can use `$(this)` to target current hover `.thumb` div and `find()` to find the child with class `option` under your current hovered `.thumb`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".thumb").hover(function() {
       $(this).find('.option').show();
   }, function() {
       $(this).find('.option').hide();
   });
});
```

or you can use `toggle()` to toggle between show and hide instead of two separate function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.thumb').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.option').toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to show and hide a child element if you mouse over an element, you can try this code which will work perfectly for your scenario.

Try Demo @ http://jsfiddle.net/FTnsn/

`$(function() {
    $('.thumb').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('.option').toggle();
    });
});`

Let me know if I misinterpret your problem...